How to pass a typedef enum from a python script to a C library?
I do have a C library with a defs.h containing a custom typedef
typedef enum _CustomParam
{
    OptionOne,  /// Default 0
    OptionTwo,  /// Default 0
} CustomParam;

and a lib.h containing the function:
extern "C"
{
    /// @param[in] Parameter to retrieve value for
    /// @return the parameter value
    /// @retval -1 if the retrieval could not be made
    LIB_EXPORT double getParam(CustomParam param);

    /// @param[in] param Parameter to set
    /// @param[in] val the value to set the parameter to
    /// @retval 0 if setting the parameter was successful
    /// @retval -1 if setting the parameter failed
    LIB_EXPORT int setParam(CustomParam param, double value);
}

I now implemented a python script to use this function:
# def.py
from ctypes import *

class CustomParam(c_int):
    OptionOne = 0
    OptionTwo = 1

# main.py
from .lib import Lib
    library = Lib("lib/lib.dll")
    library.init()

# lib.py
from def.h import *
def __init__(self, libpath):
    super().__init__()
    self.lib = CDLL(libpath)

def init(self):
    self.lib.getParam.argtypes = [CustomParam]
    self.lib.getParam.restype = c_double
    result = self.lib.getParam(CustomParam.OptionOne)
    print("Parameter: ", result)

result is always -1. No matter if I set or get a Parameter.
In general: All functions which take the CustomParam as an input fail. All functions with generic input formats (like e.g. c_int) do work correctly. That's why I guess that my Input for getParam might be in an unexpected format. I also tried to get change the formats to (c_int(0)) or 0 instead of CustomParam.OptionOne (Which should be the same).
Any suggestions on how I can use a C typedef enum as an input in my python script to call a function from a C library?

Please use proper indentation.

You are right. Fixed it. Thank you for pointing it out

Passing an enum works fine for me under Windows. Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example.
